# MFC component defocus event handler

Tags: c++, mfc, event-handling, uicomponents

Is there a standard way to handle MFC Edit box defocus event? I mean if I click on the box enter something and then move on on the other component handling event gets fired? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Windows send the [WM_KILLFOCUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646282%28VS.85%29.aspx).

MFC uses the `EN_KILLFOCUS` for edit boxes, IIRC.